# Vue3 with Vuex4: v-for only rendering a few -- but not all -- items in an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, v-for

First time user and beginner developer here - thank you in advance for your help!

So, I'm making a simple web app that takes the http JSON response from an API, and renders a nicer looking list of results.  For some reason, however, when render the item with a v-for directive, only the first few results in the response array are showing up.  Here is my main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

import App from './App.vue'
import Axios from "axios";

const store = createStore({
    state(){
        return {
            searchResults: null,
        }
    },
    getters: {

    },
    mutations: {
        setResults(state, payload){
            state.searchResults = payload.claims;
        },
        clearResults(state){
            state.searchResults = null;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        submitSearch(context, payload) {
            context.commit('clearResults');
            Axios.request({
              baseURL: "https://factchecktools.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/claims:search",
              method: "get",
              params: {
                languageCode: "en",
                query: payload.searchTerm,
                pageSize: 100,
                key: "AIzaSyCqYStCPuaamvXv1qcuWeof0pEx8TguXeY",
              },
            })
              .then((response) => {
                context.commit('setResults', {claims: response.data.claims})
                //this.$store.dispatch('setResults', {result: response.data.claims})
                //this.searchResults = response.data.claims;
                //this.$emit("search-results", this.searchResults);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
        },

    },
})
```

Here is my app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <ClaimSearch @search-results="setResults" />
    <ResultCard
      v-for="(result, index) in searchResults"
      :key="index"
      :claim="result.text"
      :claimant="result.claimant"
      :date="result.claimDate"
      :reviews="result.claimReview"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ClaimSearch from "./components/ClaimSearch.vue";
import ResultCard from "./components/ResultCard.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ClaimSearch,
    ResultCard,
  },
  computed: {
    searchResults(){
      return this.$store.state.searchResults;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Here's my ClaimSearch.vue component:

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitSearch" class="searchBar">
    <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm" />
    <button type="submit">Is it true?</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      searchTerm: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    submitSearch(){
      this.$store.dispatch('submitSearch', {searchTerm: this.searchTerm})
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

And finally, here's my ResultCar.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="resultCard">
    <div class="claimCard">
      <h3>The Claim:</h3>
      <p>{{ claim }} - {{ claimant }}, on {{ date.slice(0, 10) }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="checkCard">
      <h3>Fact Check:</h3>
      <hr />

      <div v-for="review in reviewList" :key="review.url">
        <b>{{ review.publisher.name }}</b>
        rated this claim as "<b>{{ review.textualRating }}</b
        >". <br />
        Source: "<a :href="review.url" target="_blank"> {{ review.title }} </a>"
        <br />
        - published {{ review.reviewDate.slice(0, 10) }}. <br />
        <hr />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["claim", "claimant", "date", "reviews"],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    reviewList() {
      return this.reviews;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

With the above code, when the API call gets, say, an array of 100 items, only the first five or six show up -- while some queries don't show up at all.  What gives?

Thanks again in advance -- super noob I know!

Answer (score 2):

Welp, I fixed the issue by simply building and deploying the app.  I guess there's something going on with Vue that the v-for function breaks when testing on local development server?

Thanks anyway!